# Limpar Form1 e adicionar novas coisas, como o sistema de rooms do game maker

Tags: c#, winforms

Opa! Galera, como eu faço pra limpar um form e colocar novos elementos dentro? Por exemplo: Algo parecido com uma tela de instalação quando clicamos em Next.

Edit1: 
Por exemplo, essa tela:
[image: Room0]
Virar essa tela ao clicar em algum ícone de boneco:
[image: Room1]
De maneira que uma não fique em cima da outra, simplesmente se alternem.

Comment: Por favor, seja mais específico. Limpar um form é `form.Components.Clear()`, mas não parece que é isso você quer...

Comment: Vou editar e mostrar um projeto que eu fiz no game maker

Comment: Prontinho, fiz a edição.

Comment: Crie um tabcontrol e vá alterando de abas ao clicar, ou então crie vários panels e vá mudando a visibilidade. São as únicas formas.

Comment: Porém nenhuma das duas formas é parecida com oque eu quero, o TabControl até seria se tivesse uma forma de retirar as abas que ficam em cima

Comment: E quem disse que não tem como? **=)** Vou criar um exemplo pra você.

Comment: Beleza obrigado aew, fico no aguardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simular isso usando um TabControl.

1. Mude as propriedades **`ItemSize`** e **`SizeMode`** do TabControl

   ```
   tabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
   tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
   ```

   Também é possível mudar usando a janela Properties no design do form.
   Provavelmente isso vai deixar uma bordinha no canto do TabControl, você pode mudar a propriedade `Appearance` para fazer essa bordinha desaparecer.

   ```
   tabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
   ```
2. Crie os eventos dos botões mudando a TabPage selecionada.

   ```
   private void btAnterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
   }

   private void bProximo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
   }
   ```

Observação: você pode usar a janela **document outline** (Ctrl + W, U) para trocar a aba vísivel em tempo de design.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim permanece as abas, elas eram pra ser invisíveis

Comment: Então você fez algo errado, porque pra mim não aparece nada. Tem como mostrar um print?

Comment: https://scontent.fcpv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/13589097_1005138562937900_351858082_o.png?oh=5196e21e5b4f1c7ee2fa24f91a54ddea&oe=57857B74

Comment: Você alterou as propriedades que eu falei por onde?

Comment: Pela tela de propriedades mesmo, mas oque você fez foi esconder, eu quero realmente que não exista entendeu?

Comment: Como assim que **não exista**? Elas não vão aparecer, isso é suficiente. Não tem outra forma de fazer, jovem.

Comment: Ow! Aprendi a usar o Panel direitinho! Resolvi meu problema :D

Comment: Graças a você <3